# How to Serialize String in Scala

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, apache-kafka

I have a DStream[String,String]. I use foreachRDD to get every RDD and publish it in Kafka. 
The problem I have come across is I need to guarentee String is serialized and the value of my RDD is not serializable because an unknown reason. Kafka expects to get a StringSerializer as Value, but as you can see in the image below my DStream doesn´t have serialized String. How can I convert String not serializable to serializabel before publish to Kafka? I could change kafConf but I would prefer change value instead Kafka configuration.

```
  def kafkaConf(brokers : String) = {
    val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props
  }
```

[Error publishing in kafka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foy1V.png)

Comment: Why don't you share your producer's code?

Comment: Spark Streaming is deprecated. Why aren't you using Structured Streaming? And please don't use images for errors

Comment: Sorry for not having given more details about my error. I have received an answer from my teachers about what was the problem. The proble was with the spark context. I was passing as a parameter the spark context and it is not serializable. I had to pass it through a variable and then it is serializable. It has been a little weird... but it is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not saying anything about strings. A Dstream is not serializable, meaning you've shared part of it between executor scopes, making Spark think it needs to serialize it

You really should show all your code, but to use a KafkaProducer is Spark Streaming, you need to use foreachPartition, then create a Producer inside that block.

For each partition, you loop over each RDD, then use the KafkaProducer.send method

You don't need to worry about serialization unless you want to define your own

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say the exact solution without the code. I think your problem is not related to Kafka's properties.

In the error log, Spark tries to serialize a class and it got failed.

Please check your code inside the foreachRDD block. I think you used an unserializable class. Check you classes and add the Serializable implements to your class if you can. or Just try to use the String type.

Comment: In the end the problem was with spark context. I was passing the spark context as a parameter and spark context is not serializable.